# Is a visa needed for a stopover in USA for a person holding a Canadian permanent resident visa?

Tags: visas, usa, transit, canada

I have a concern about my approaching flight, I just got my permanent resident visa for Canada. I have a connecting flight from Manila to San Francisco USA, then to Toronto. I will just stay two hours at the San Francisco airport for my connecting flight.

Do I need papers or a visa from the US embassy so they will not hold me or stop me from flying to Canada?

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered before, but the answer is **Yes**, the requirements for transit are the same as for entering the U.S. So you would need a visa unless you are the national of a Visa Waiver country.